# Запуск скрипта в iframe

Tags: html, iframe, javascript

Есть следующий, код:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('result_frame').contentDocument;

frame.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
frame.write("<html><head><script>"+ JSCodeEditor.getValue() +"</script></head><body>"+ HTMLCodeEditor.getValue() +"</body></html>");
```

Проблема в том, что html+js код добавляется во фрейм, но сам скрипт не срабатывает. Подскажите что делать.

Comment: ошибки в консоли есть?

Answer (score 2):

Вместо последней строки попробуйте

```
frame.write("<html><head><script>" + JSCodeEditor.getValue() + "</" + "script></head><body>" + HTMLCodeEditor.getValue() + "</body></html>");
```